# In IIS, how is cshtml is added to a link without extension and test it out?

Tags: iis

We have an IIS (version 10.x) site of html and cshtml pages. There is a top-level page called abc.cshtml. All of the following three links are resolved to the same page:

```
http://example.org/abc.cshtml
http://example.org/abc
http://example.org/abc/
```

I am not able to see any related redirect/rewrite rules in web.config. It seems that IIS automatically adds `.cshtml` extension to a link without extension and test it out. I would like to know how IIS resolve the links such as `http://example.org/abc` and `http://example.org/abc/` and how to configure this behavior.

Note that I also have a page call test.html in the top level, but IIS does not resolve http://example.org/test to http://example.org/test.html and, instead, produce a 404 error.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of web appplication you have used now? MVC?  It seems your application route config modify the url.

Comment: The site does not use MVC. It is purely a simple site with cshtml and html pages.

Comment: I guess this is related with the application's route config. So I need to know which kinds of the asp.net application you have used to reproduce the issue.